# How to send hashmap or json with google analytics in android

Tags: android, json, google-analytics, hashmap, google-analytics-firebase

I want to send hashmap of values related to event using Google Analytics. I want to know it is possible or not nothing is mentioned in Google analytics documentation for it most of the analytics tools allow sending either hashmap or json don't see any option available in Google analytics.

Currently I am using custom dimensions to achieve this but this isn't meeting my requirements I want to know is it possible to send hashmap or json using GA and how

Comment: why you need send hashmap to GA , have you know about event?

Comment: I want to send attributes related to events suppose a user clicks on product I want to send product name, id, price, category related to product

Answer (score -1):

after get reference to your tracker build an event with desired data , I think this enough number of columns to send your data

```
 Field Name      Type        Required        Description
  Category      String         Yes         The event category
  Action        String         Yes         The event action
  Label         String          No         The event label
  Value          Long           No         The event value



Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
        TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    // Build and send an Event. 
    t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
        .setCategory(getString(categoryId))
        .setAction(getString(actionId))
        .setLabel(getString(labelId))
        .build());
```

reference 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/events

**Update**

if you are using Firebase Analytics event give your more feasibility to add data via bundle

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

if you need custom event with custom params

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("image_name", name);
params.putString("full_text", text);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("share_image", params);
```

but note

> Custom parameters: Custom parameters are not represented directly in
>   your Analytics reports, but they can be used as filters in audience
>   definitions that can be applied to every report.

reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events